# edittext hides behind titlebar when soft keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-xml, android-softkeyboard

Have googled a lot but couldnt find a satisfying solution. The below screenshot depicts the issue I am facing.

[image]

Edittext hides behind titlebar when soft keyboard is visible. I have put

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

property in the main layout. If i remove this property then the layout works fine.But the design requirement needs the form to be in center.I have tried everything.Tried using scrollview and putting this into manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

Have also tried "adjustPan" and it does works.But in this case the entire form is not pushed up.the edittext 'MobileNo' and the button stays hidden behind soft keyboard.

Layout xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:padding="5dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="324dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#39CCCCCC"
        android:orientation="vertical"
       android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:padding="5dp" 
        >

     <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/edittext_dimen"
        android:hint="@string/register_name"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_bg"   
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"/>

 <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/edittext_dimen"
        android:hint="@string/register_emailid"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_bg"   
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
       android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

 <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/edittext_dimen"
        android:hint="@string/register_pass_hint"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_bg"   
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
       android:inputType="textPassword" />

 <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_confpassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/edittext_dimen"
        android:hint="@string/register_confpass"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_bg"   
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
       android:inputType="textPassword" />

 <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_mobile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/edittext_dimen"
        android:hint="@string/register_mobile"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_bg"   
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:maxLength="11"
        android:inputType="phone"/>



 <Button android:id="@+id/signup_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/edittext_dimen"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/register_signup"
         android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="#3F799F"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there any solution for this? Any workaround that could help me achieve my goal? please reply with your views and suggestions.

If you are not able to understand my doubt.Please feel free to ask.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Its because you have use relative layout. I may be wrong but you have given button to allign to bottom true, as well as other relationship above to the button. Post your XML file that clears IDEA.

Comment: The only control you have over what happens when the keyboard comes up is that soft input mode, and the only choices are pan and resize.  You may have layout changes you can make to improve things, but there's no setting for the keyboard that will fix things.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot -- No I am using LinearLayout..Will Update the question with xml code in a few..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I explain Your mistakes. You have given liner layout hight as 324dp .so when Keyboard open Linear Layout require that much space in screen so it goes up and not visible Your first edittext.

Use relative layout instead.

Wait for some moment I give you modified XML with change. till time check your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#39CCCCCC"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:hint="password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_confpassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:hint="Confirm password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_mobile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:hint="register"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:maxLength="11"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signup_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#3F799F"
        android:text="signup"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity Tag in manifest write this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"`

I change your dimention, size, color also String resourch

Comment: yes if i set the linearlayout's height to wrap content.. edittext doesnt hides behind the titlebar but then mobile number and signup button hides behind softkeyboard and it doesnt even scrolls when the keyboard is visible.I want that the user should be able to scroll till the signup button even when the keyboard is active

Comment: Hey thanx.. the issue is solved.. i changed the linearlayout's height to wrap content as you suggested and put it inside scrollview and mentioned this in manisfest android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"..This is working even if the main layout is LinearLayout.Thanx again.:)

Answer (score 1):

add `adjustPan` in manifest under `activity` tag

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"
```